# Print State of React-Redux Application in Developer Tools

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, developer-tools

I'm a react-redux beginner and this may seem like a trivial and kind of stupid question but I did not manage to find a satisfactory answer.

I have a react-redux application and receive a kind of complicated data structure from an API, the details don't matter I believe.

I want to know if there is a tool that allows us to write some quick REPL-style commands in the console or in the debugger. I currently have react and redux developer tools and a logger middleware which is perfect for seeing the evolution of the state and logging but I can not manage to go through/inspect the nested data I receive.

Thanks in advance folks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's entirely what you are after, but can't you just keep a ref to the store on the window object? That way you can access it from the console?

```
var yourStore = createStore(...); 
window.store = store;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, exactly what I needed !